# How can i add an index to each item in a java List to be processed in parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have a List of `Rec`'s and I want to process them all in parallel, by calling some method `foo()`.

`foo()` may flag some `Rec`'s as erroneous and at the end all the error recs are reported by their index position (e.g. "rec 12 is not valid").
So I want to either pass the index position of each Rec to foo(), or set the index into each Rec before calling foo.
What I attempted to do (shown below) is first, sequentially, set the index to each Rec,
and then in parallel call foo on each. Is there a better way to do this?

```
List<Rec> recs;
class Rec {
    private int recordIndex;
    public void setRecordIndex( int index) { recordIndex = index; }
    //more memebers and getter to the above...
}

//somewhere in the code
int index = 0;
recs.stream().forEach(rec -> rec.setRecordIndex(index++));
//the compiler complains about the index++ above, says it should be final
rec.parallelStream().forEach(rec -> foo(ProgressInfo, rec));
```

Is there a better way to do this overall? and if not, is there a way to fix the compilation error and still use stream? (instead of looping)

Comment: Is it not using a boolean to set the valid state and collecting at the end a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `IntStream`, also I would recommend using just one `Stream`:

```
IntStream.range(0, recs.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> {
       Rec rec = recs.get(i);
       rec.setRecordIndex(i);
       return rec;
    })
    .parallel()
    .forEach(rec -> foo(ProgressInfo, rec));
```

Altough it is discouraged to modify a state in `streams` so instead of setting the `index` inside the `mapToObj` it would probably better to return a new object. E.g. something like this:

```
.mapToObj(i -> {
   Rec copy = new Rec(recs.get(i)); // copy constructor
   copy.setRecordIndex(i);
   return copy;
})
```

---

Depending on the `List` implementation you're using (`ArrayList` performs better than `LinkedList` when using *index-access*), you could also use following snippet. But the use of [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#peek-java.util.function.IntConsumer-) in productive code is a bit controversial.

```
IntStream.range(0, recs.size())
   .peek(i -> recs.get(i).setRecordIndex(i))
   .parallel()
   .forEach(i -> foo(ProgressInfo, recs.get(i));
```

Comment: There is no fundamental difference in the snippets regarding the `List` implementation, all of your variants call `get(int)`, Whether you run it once per element or twice as in your last snippet, doesn’t make much difference. Regarding the side effects, there’s also not much difference between doing them in a `map` operation or within a `peek`. Creating a new object like in your second variant is the cleanest option, but keep in mind that the OP said, passing the index to `foo` is also ok, i.e. `IntStream.range(0, recs.size()) .parallel() .forEach(ix -> foo(progressInfo, ix, recs.get(ix)))`…

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IntStream`:

```
IntStream.range(0, recs.size())
         .forEach(i -> recs.get(i).setRecordIndex(i));
```

That simply uses a stream of numbers from `0` to `recs.size() - 1`, and calls `recs.get` for each of number.